# ReactNative OnRefresh is never called in RefreshControl for IOS (but works in Android)

Tags: react-native

Copying and pasting into Snack a simple RefreshControl example from the official documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol): the onRefresh method doesn't seem to be ever called when pulling to refresh in  IOS emulator (but it's working on Android emulator).

### Reproducible Demo

https://snack.expo.io/HJ8loC5RX

Comment: Are you sure `onRefresh` is not called? Because the logs in your demo print out appropriate message into console.

Maybe you're confused why refresh control is not spinning? In that case don't forget to set `isRefreshing` property

Comment: Hi @AyJay thank you for checkin it out, I made a video to show that in my experience no logs get printed when pulling down with IOS simulator. Here is the link:
https://www.useloom.com/share/81bfa0d94ed54d2199181534bf900a19

Comment: From video it doesnt seem you are triggering refresh. Try pulling scroll view down more, until spinner is filled.

Comment: arrgh, you are right! my bad, so I actually didn't complete the Pull Down gesture in the simulator!

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I wasn't finishing the Pull Down gesture the correct way in the simulator, but only initiating it.